# How to estimate the hazardousness of the smoke of a lipo fire?

Tags: safety

As generally known lithium polymer batteries (lipos) may catch fire, for example as consequence of deep discharge, overcharge, (internal) short circuit etc.

As a hobby rc car driver, I am thinking about the dangers of a possible lipo fire. To prevent the fire one could use a lipo box like [batsafe](https://www.bat-safe.com/). However this [doesn't filter](https://www.bat-safe.com/faq) toxic fumes.

Now there are different opinions found on the net about those fumes, one (as in the faq of bat-safe) says that the fumes dissipate over time. So to say, after a possible fire inside of the box, you just have to open your windows for a few hours or days and everything is gone.

Other people say that parts of this toxic mixture could make a complete house uninhabitable, because material will distribute all over your house and emit toxic fumes, which will make you ill over time (see [here](https://www.rc-modellbau-portal.de/index.php?threads/der-wahnsinn-um-lipos.5636/#post-121921))

> But what really causes damage is the extreme smoke development.
> Besides highly toxic and corrodes your lungs with every breath
> irreversible.
>
> No use for a batsave or ammunition box, the smoke will find its way,
> these things are only good to seal off fire from the rest of the
> apartment. The only exception would be a connection to the outside.
>
> This extremely dense smoke will push you through all the
> cracks,through all the boxes, through all doors (even closed) in the
> house......
>
> .....The result is an uninhabitable apartment that must be completely
> gutted.
>
> At least that was always, without exception, the statement of the
> damaged ones as the forums were still full of reports about lipo
> fires.
>
> Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

However I don't see how to estimate which opinion is true. So I try to post this as a kind of [fermi question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_problem) to chemistry stackexchange and hope for some insights.

You may assume that four 3s lipos like [this](https://traxxas.com/products/parts/batteries/idpowercellbatteries/lipo/2849X-4000mah-111v-3S-25C) burn inside of a lipo box (which prevents the fire) in a basement of a house in a room with 100 m^3 air and the possibility to open larger windows or a door, if needed after the accident.

Comment: There isn't stuff like lead of Hg in such batteries. Electrolyte won't burn. That leaves solvent and polymer - not entirely pleasant, but at least some of them aren't all that  bad to burn.

Comment: In general, I wouldn't worry *too much*. Not any more than some random piece of plastic catching fire.